# Select specified value when having duplicate keys

Tags: sql, duplicates, identifier

So I have table with for example rented items

```
 id | itemID | state
 3  |      2 |     0
 2  |      2 |     1
 1  |      2 |     1
```

State represents if the item was rented in past. `0 = currently rented`

Table with items:

```
id | item   | condition
1  | showel |      good
2  |    saw |        ok
```

Now i want to select items which are not currently rented, i ended up with this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT CASE WHEN b.itemID = a.id AND b.state = 0 THEN 1
  ELSE 0 END AS itemState, a.condition AS condition
  FROM items AS a
  LEFT JOIN rented AS b ON a.id = b.item_id
) AS states
WHERE states.itemState = 0
```

But SQL is returning that saw[id=2] is currently free, but that's not true.

Is there any way how to fix SQL statement?

// EDIT: I need to keep duplicate itemIDs in table rented

Comment: Since you want to keep duplicates `ItemID`s, then the same `ItemId` will have different states for the same `ItemId` because of duplicates, and what about `items` that are in `items` table and are not in `rented` table like the itemid = 1, because you are using `LEFT JOIN`? Can you please paste the desired output that you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are after, you could achieve it like this:

```
SELECT outerA.*
  FROM items AS outerA
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT innerA.*
                 FROM rented AS innerA
                   JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id 
                           FROM rented 
                           GROUP BY itemID) AS innerB
                     ON innerB.id = innerA.id) AS outerB
      ON outerB.itemID = outerA.id
  WHERE outerB.state IS NULL
    OR outerB.state = 1;
```

It will choose any item, that either has never been rented or its last entry in `rented` table indicates that it is not currently rented.

See, also, this **[short demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ff8e/3)**.

Comment: Thank's this helped me a lot, i owe you six pack of beer :)

Comment: Just upvote my answer and we can call it even :D Always glad to help :)